# Is there any syntax that can shorten this code?

Tags: c++

Is there anyway i can shorten this code? its so bulky!

```
switch(line){
    case 1:
      llemu::editLable(line1, fmt);
    break;
    case 2:
      llemu::editLable(line2, fmt);
    break;
    case 3:
      llemu::editLable(line3, fmt);
    break;
    case 4:
      llemu::editLable(line4, fmt);
    break;
    case 5:
      llemu::editLable(line5, fmt);
    break;
    case 6:
      llemu::editLable(line6, fmt);
    break;
    case 7:
      llemu::editLable(line7, fmt);
    break;
    case 8:
      llemu::editLable(line8, fmt);
    break;
  }
```

Is there a way to use a variable value as a/ a part of a variable name? Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Firs of all, this code most likely has a bug - it lacks `break`s in the end of the case labels. Second of all, it is impossible to give any advice without context, so question lacks [mcve]

Comment: Are you willing to group all of the `line1` through `line8` into an array?

Comment: @SergeyA Where else would you put a `break`?

Comment: I do not see reason to close this question (as seeking debugging help). Problem is pretty clear. It is nice to see that newbie notices bad code without external feedback and ask for a solution. For most newbies this code would be fine.

Comment: I believe there is another solution (im just wanting to learn) with using the "##" syntax(what is it called?). Ive saw it in other people's code. ive heard that it can "stick" things together?

Comment: @EdenCheung That's macro concatenation in the preprocessor. Probably not what you want. In fact C++ simply does not have "variable variables" in the sense that you're thinking of, but that's okay because Paul's got the right answer :)

Comment: @RickPat sorry, formatting tricked me.

Comment: Will this work?`#define REGISTER_LINE(x) line##x`

Comment: So i could do `llemu::editLabel(REGISTER_LINE(line),fmt)`

Answer (score 5):

Simply place all of your `line1`, `line2`, ... into an array `lines`.
Then your code becomes:

```
if (line >= 1 && line <= 8) {
    llemu::editLable(lines[line - 1], fmt);
}
```